# Which sentence is most acceptable when describing the current time period?

Tags: grammar, dates

I would like to know which of these two sentences have the most acceptable form when describing the current time period.

```
Why do so many people **today** have no values

Why do so many people have no values **these days**
```

Thanks in advance for any help in sharing knowledge.

Comment: This is a style choice; both are acceptable. I do agree, however, that the first sounds much better. To me, it's much more concise and less *folksy.* But again, it's your choice and depends on who you're talking to.

Answer (score 1):

They are both fine, but they may be slightly different in a way that is difficult to explain.

While both are likely to be used in the context of historical contrast, I think I would be more likely to use *today* for longer more defined periods and *these days* for shorter less defined periods.  *These days* also feels more informal.

Examples:

> In the 1300's people believed x, but *today* we know that ....
>
> It used to be that you didn't do that, but *these days* kids will...

I would not assert for a minute that the above is universal.  The above is just my feel and experience.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to say is that, if these are questions, they have to be rewritten as:

> Why do so many people today have no values?

and

> Why do so many people have no values these days?

Once you’ve done that, it doesn’t much matter whether you use *today* or *these days*.

Comment: You changed your post after I had commented, so ignore the first part of my answwer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I corrected my question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I do not like either sentence, and not because they are incorrect grammatically.

Young people today have values, as do young people of any era, generation, or culture.  If you want to sound less hyperbolic, I suggest you expand upon (or unpack) what you mean by *no values*.  You can do this is at least two ways:

1. Focus on a specific area of values in which young people could do much better, and then go on to explain how and why.  For example,

   - Young people today do not seem to value patience, and consequently they seem always to be in a hurry.
   - Young people today do not seem to value reflective thinking in the quietness of one's own thoughts, preferring instead a constant barrage of electronic media.
   - Young people today do not seem to value education for the sake of education, but only as a tool to get a well-paying job.
2. Focus on how young people are not fully aware of values in general, such that they find it difficult--and do not see the need--to examine their true values and what those values say about them.  For example,

   - Young people today do not seem to be aware of the importance of being proactive in determining what values they will live by and why.
   - When asked "What are the values you live by?", young people today are very often at a loss for words, which is very sad indeed.
   - Young people need to be schooled first in what values are, and second, schooled in which values are or are not praiseworthy, and why.

Answer (score 0):

You could try: "Why do people nowadays have no values?". Nowadays is a mixture of "today" and "these days", pretty much. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The surmised premise of the intended question is lacking logical basis.
 
Why do so many people today have no values?
In this sentence, "no" is a sum equaling zero. Rewritten:
Why do so many people today have zero values?
This is where the logical breakdown occurs, because every person has values. It seems the author is instead suggesting that:
*he no longer shares the same values as people today because values of the general population have changed, or
*he does share the same values as people today, but without the same priority.
If either of these are the case, then the question may be rewritten:
Why are so many people today without the same values as me?
On the other hand, if the intent of the sentence is a quote, then consider the character's voice. If the character does not value grammar nor the recognition of logical fallacy, then rewritten:
"People today-- why they ain't got no values?"